# On "$u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \implies u$ improperly integrable $\implies$ $u$ has convergent principal value integral" and a "quasi-converse" result

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

How can we prove the following result?

> 1. $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \implies u$ [improperly integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_Riemann_integrals_and_Lebesgue_integrals) (that is, the improper integral on $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent)$\implies$ $u$ has convergent principal value integral [[Wikipedia link: formulations 1 and 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation)] and we have $$\int_\mathbb{R} u(x) dx \text{ (Lebesgue int.)} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u(x) dx \text{ (improper int.)}  = \text{ principal value int.} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u(x) dx. $$
> 2. $u \ge 0$ and $u$ has convergent [principal value integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation) $\implies$ $u$ improperly integrable.
> 3. $u \ge 0$  and $u$ improperly integrable $\implies $ $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: The Lebesgue integral has various convergence theorems ...

Comment: @user251257 What are you thinking about precisely?

Answer (score 1):

1. If a function $u$ is Lebesgue integrable, then it is absolutely integrable. Therefore, by the dominated convergence theorem
   $$
      \lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty \\ b\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty\\b\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{[a,b]}f(x)dx
      =\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx.
   $$
   (Technically you have to deal with limits of sequences of numbers $a$ and $b$, but that's not hard to extend to the above case.) The dominated convergence theorem applies because $|\chi_{[a,b]}f| \le |f|$ for all $a,b$. Once you know the above holds, then the CPV integral holds because it is a special case of the above

2 & 3. For these cases, if $u \ge 0$, then the monotone convergence theorem applies instead.

Comment: How does the monotone convergence theorem apply in these circumstances?

Comment: @Axel : $\chi_{I} \le \chi_{J}$ if $I \subseteq J$.